# What’s the proper ratio when mixing an “attach & spray” weed killer with water?

Tags: weed-control, weeds

I have an “attach & spray” weed killer but need to treat weeds in an area that doesn’t have faucets nearby. I’m thinking  of using a 1-gallon pump sprayer instead of a hose. I read through the directions but couldn’t find the ratio for mixing it with water. What should be the ratio when mixing this weed killer with water in the jug?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is a tricky question because the product you have may not be as concentrated as the same product meant for manual spraying. According to [this site](https://grass-killer.com/reviews/bayer-advanced-weed-killer-review/), but quite possibly referring to a different concentration of the product:

> Since BioAdvanced [a new name for Bayer] is fully concentrated, 3.2 fluid ounces (6 1/2 tablespoons) can dissolve in 1 gallon of water. This volume is enough to cover 500 square feet. If your lawn is very dusty, water it completely 1 or 2 days before applying BioAdvanced.

If the concentration on the reviewed product and your product are the same, then add about 3 ounces of product to your sprayer.

**Important Note!**

That website states that the Bayer product line was replaced by the BioAdvanced line in 2018, which makes your product at least four years old. It may no longer be effective - or as effective - as it was when it was manufactured. According to the [Farm Progress site](https://www.farmprogress.com/herbicide/should-you-use-old-herbicides-storage), quoting Fred Whitford, director of Purdue University Pesticide Programs:

> "Most pesticides are still effective and could be used within three years of manufacture if they were stored properly. If the container is open, don’t apply the product without asking lots of questions.”

It's a crapshoot whether your product will work as well as it's supposed to.

Purdue University has published [this guide](https://ppp.purdue.edu/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/PPP-142.pdf), "Is This Pesticide on My Shelf Still Good?" which you may want to review before spraying your lawn.

Comment: That's a very thorough answer. Thanks Jurp!

Answer (score 1):

Simple method - fill the sprayer jug using a hose connected to the  attach and spray product.

That will automatically get the same mix ratio, because it uses the same mix method.

Comment: Where does the jug get its water pressure? I didn't quite understand your answer..

Comment: Where does the jug always get it pressure from? Attach hose to faucet. Attach product to hose. Direct output of hose water+product mixture into sprayer jug. Install pump onto sprayer jug and pump until it's pressurized, like always. Carry to location away from hose, spray.

Comment: The weed killer discharge hole fans out. The opening of the 1-gallon jug is narrow. I can't think of a good way to connect the two without wasting a substantial amount of the mixture.

Comment: Discharge into a larger bucket or tub, then pour back into the sprayer?

Comment: Or a funnel works, too.